# all product page showing 404 and i could not access admin pages magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, product-page, url-key

I have copied my Magento 2 backup to my new server

now I am getting

> all product page showing 404 and I could not access admin pages magento 2

exception.log

> main.CRITICAL: Unique constraint violation found
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0):
>   Unique constraint violation found at
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:425,
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DuplicateException(code: 1062):
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `mg_report_event`
>   (`logged_at`, `event_type_id`, `object_id`, `subtype`, `store_id`)
>   VALUES ('2019-08-14 07:24:45', ?, ?, ?, ?) at
>   public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:580,
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY',
>   query was: INSERT INTO `mg_report_event` (`logged_at`,
>   `event_type_id`, `object_id`, `subtype`, `store_id`) VALUES
>   ('2019-08-14 07:24:45', ?, ?, ?, ?) at
>   public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235,
>   PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' at
>   /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"}
>   []

I have tried this answer but not working

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789752

Does anyone know how to solve this??

Comment: are you using any custom module? if yes show your `installSchema.php` file

Comment: im using many custom module...

Comment: can you check from which module is using this table `mg_report_event`?

Comment: how i can check...

Comment: in your terminal use this command `grep -rr1 "mg_report_event"`

Comment: what will do this commend ..

Comment: It will find the string `mg_report_event` in your Magento and list you where it is used

Comment: i used one module...

Comment: it will show you the path, where it's been used

Comment: controller ......

Comment: Share a screenshot after running grep command

Comment: i am going to diable that module from my site

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

If the values inside mg_report_event table is not so important. You may truncate the table.
Login into your database and run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mg_report_event
```

Comment: i tried this but not working